# Share ui-router resolve data with Angular component within state template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

In my angular app, I have a pretty standard `<navbar>` component.

This component is to be used inside the template on the following state that I've defined using ui-router:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('proverbs', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/proverbs/:lang',
        template: '<navbar></navbar><div ui-view class="absolute full-sized anim-in-out" data-anim-speed="444" data-anim-sync="false"/></div>',
        resolve: {
            proverbs: ['$stateParams', '$q', 'dataFactory', function ($stateParams, $q, dataFactory) {
                let deferred = $q.defer();
                let url = CONFIG.api + '/proverbs/' + $stateParams.lang;

                dataFactory.getData(url).then(function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            }]
        }
    })
```

As you can see I've set a resolve property to be able to share async data with this state and all its child states.

However, the component `<navbar>` doesn't know what `proverbs` is when it gets initialized:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

    angular
        .module('proverbial')
        .component('navbar', {
            templateUrl:'scripts/components/navbar/navbar.template.html',
            controller: NavbarController,
            bindings: {
                Binding: '=',
            },
        });

    NavbarController.$inject = [ '$stateParams', '$scope', 'language', 'proverbs', 'CONFIG' ];

    function NavbarController( $stateParams, $scope, language, proverbs, CONFIG ) { };
})();
```

And I get the following error when accessing the state:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: proverbsProvider <- proverbs
```

How can I access this `proverbs` data within my `navbar` component without calling `dataFactory` again?

Comment: I'm guessing that ui-router inject those resolves into the controller defined via the stateProvider, but I'm not sure. You can define a mini controller for the state that expose the injections on the scope of the controller and then provide them directly to the navbar directive.

Comment: Store the data in a service and inject that service into the component